# error while using outer join / full outer join in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

my query - select * from members outer join movies on movies.id = members.movie_id;

error :-

15:01:51    select * from members outer join movies on movies.id = members.movie_id Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'outer join movies on movies.id = members.movie_id' at line 1   0.000 sec

Comment: So you did what the error message told you to do and checked the manual for the syntax - what happened then?

Comment: remove `outer` keyword

Comment: @ jens i have to use outer keyword for the query...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes i have checked it but it just not working for outer syntax.

Comment: `FROM a OUTER JOIN b` is not valid SQL. You must specify which kind of outer join you want: `FROM a LEFT [OUTER] JOIN b`, `FROM a RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN b` (not recommended), `FROM a FULL [OUTER] JOIN b` (not available in MySQL yet)